# SBT throwing JdbcSQLExceptionSyntax exception for an PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I am running a SQL query using slick to write to a PostgreSQL DB. Why am i getting a Syntax error in SQL statement error?  Please assume all configurations are correct.

I have imported `import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._` in the client and `import slick.jdbc.H2Profile.api._` in the query builder. I have also separated postgresql and MySQL statements into different builders.

```
import bbc.rms.client.programmes.util.MySqlStringEscaper
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import slick.jdbc.H2Profile.api._

abstract class PopularBlurProgrammesQueryBuilder extends QueryBuilder with                 
MySqlStringEscaper {

  def incrementBlurScoreQuery(pid: String, date: DateTime): DBIO[Int] = {
    sqlu"""
          INSERT INTO radio.core_entity_popularity (pid, score, date)
          VALUES($pid, 1, ${flooredSQLDateTimeString(date)}
          ) ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT core_entity_popularity_pkey
          DO UPDATE
          SET score = core_entity_popularity.score + 1
    """
  }
}
```

````

```
import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._

class SlickPopularBlurProgrammesClient[T](database: Database)(implicit 
executionContext: ExecutionContext)
  extends PopularBlurProgrammesQueryBuilder with 
PopularBlurProgrammesClient[T] {

override def writeBlurIncrementedScore(pid: String, date: DateTime): 
 Future[Int] = {
   database.run(incrementBlurScoreQuery(pid, date))
  }
}
```

Expected result is that the exception is not thrown and the integration tests pass. Integration test:

```
val currentDate = dateTimeFormat.parseDateTime("2018-12-19 16:00:00")
client.writeBlurIncrementedScore("pid", currentDate)
whenReady(client.writeBlurIncrementedScore("pid", currentDate)) { 
updatedRows =>
    updatedRows must be equalTo 1
  }
}
```

stack trace:

```
    org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "
      INSERT INTO radio.core_entity_popularity (pid, score, date)
      VALUES(?, 1, ?
      ) ON[*] CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT core_entity_popularity_pkey
      DO UPDATE
      SET score = core_entity_popularity.score + 1
    "; SQL statement:

      INSERT INTO radio.core_entity_popularity (pid, score, date)
      VALUES(?, 1, ?
      ) ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT core_entity_popularity_pkey
      DO UPDATE
      SET score = core_entity_popularity.score + 1
 [42000-193]
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "
      INSERT INTO radio.core_entity_popularity (pid, score, date)
      VALUES(?, 1, ?
      ) ON[*] CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT core_entity_popularity_pkey
      DO UPDATE
      SET score = core_entity_popularity.score + 1
"; SQL statement:

      INSERT INTO radio.core_entity_popularity (pid, score, date)
      VALUES(?, 1, ?
      ) ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT core_entity_popularity_pkey
      DO UPDATE
      SET score = core_entity_popularity.score + 1
 [42000-193]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:191)
at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:530)
at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:257)
at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:561)
at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:502)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1203)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:287)
at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$SessionDef$class.prepareStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:336)
at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.prepareStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:448)
at slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.results(StatementInvoker.scala:32)
at slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.iteratorTo(StatementInvoker.scala:21)
at slick.jdbc.Invoker$class.first(Invoker.scala:30)
at slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.first(StatementInvoker.scala:15)
at slick.jdbc.StreamingInvokerAction$HeadAction.run(StreamingInvokerAction.scala:52)
at slick.jdbc.StreamingInvokerAction$HeadAction.run(StreamingInvokerAction.scala:51)
at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$2.liftedTree1$1(BasicBackend.scala:275)
at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$2.run(BasicBackend.scala:275)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you update your question to include the stack trace that SBT outputs when the error occurs.

Comment: @Eric included now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the postgreSQL is very strict on expressions and did not like the way the date was handled. It didn't explicitly know if the date value was a Timestamp so I had to explicitly call the postgreSQL function `to_timestamp(text, text)` and also add `$` to use variables in the query.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that you are submitting a specific PostgreSQL query to an H2 database.

The `INSERT` syntax for PostgreSQL allow the key `ON CONFLICT`

> ```
> [ WITH [ RECURSIVE ] with_query [, ...] ]
> INSERT INTO table_name [ AS alias ] [ ( column_name [, ...] ) ]
>      { DEFAULT VALUES | VALUES ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) [, ...] | query }
>      [ ON CONFLICT [ conflict_target ] conflict_action ]
>      [ RETURNING * | output_expression [ [ AS ] output_name ] [, ...] ]
>
> where conflict_target can be one of:
>
>      ( { index_column_name | ( index_expression ) } [ COLLATE collation ] [ opclass ] [, ...] ) [ WHERE index_predicate ]
>      ON CONSTRAINT constraint_name
>
> and conflict_action is one of:
>
>      DO NOTHING
>      DO UPDATE SET { column_name = { expression | DEFAULT } |
>                 ( column_name [, ...] ) = ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) |
>                 ( column_name [, ...] ) = ( sub-SELECT )
>               } [, ...]
>           [ WHERE condition ]
> ```

from [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html)

While the H2 `INSERT` syntax is

> ```
> INSERT INTO tableName 
> { [ ( columnName [,...] ) ] 
> { VALUES 
> { ( { DEFAULT | expression } [,...] ) } [,...] | [ DIRECT ] [ SORTED ] select } } | 
> { SET { columnName = { DEFAULT | expression } } [,...] }
> ```

from [H2 DB docs](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#insert)

Comment: I have already tried to replace the H2 import and replaces it with postgresQL.api._ but still no luck first thing i tried.

Comment: You should not only try to change that import. That won't help. The error is from the DBMS engine itself. You have to change the db connections to a real Postgres instance, instead of an H2 one.

Comment: However, I have already insured that the db connection is to a postgress instance as the tests stub this. All configurations have been checked.